# Getting hold of FastInfoset readers and writers

Tags: java, xml, fastinfoset

JDK 1.6 includes the capability for using FastInfoset web services via the JAX-WS API.  The  implementations of these are hidden deep inside `com.sun.xml.internal`, with package names designed to put the fear of god into any sensible java developer (e.g. `com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.stax.StAXDocumentParser` (which implements `XMLStreamReader`) and `com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.stax.StAXDocumentSerializer` (which implements `XMLStreamWriter`).

My understanding is that the use of these FastInfoset implementations is part of the internal JAX-WS content negotiation logic, and therefore not exposed to the public API.  However, I want to make explicit use of the FastInfoset implementations, using their public STAX interfaces, and referably via a public factory class, rather than direct reference to these internal packages.

Does anyone know if this facility is available, perhaps via the standard STAX factories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XMLInputFactory](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html) and [XMLOutputFactory](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.html) seem plausible.

Each has three implementations in my environment, one of which is cxf (ruled-out), one from codehaus (ruled-out), the other is from the fast infoset package you are referring to.

I found this using Eclipse "References", because the javadoc doesn't include the "Use" section.

Comment: But those factories will just give you back which implementation they think is best, you can't say "I want a FastInfoset implementation"... or can you?

Comment: I think you cant - they use the static FactoryFinder.find method. But I think by default they should return what you need.

Comment: Looks like I'll need to pass in the classname of the FastInfoset implementation when I use `XMLInputFactory.newFactory()`. It's not much better than instantiating it directly, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Seems there's a hilarious bug in Java6... the return type of `XmlOutputFactory.newFactory()` is `XmlInputFactory`. Great quality control on the API spec, there.